# Sign and Encryption to XML for SOAP services in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, soap, digital-signature

I need create a logic in NodeJS that allow sign and encrypt XML for communications SOAP.

In the tag header what values would go in its content

```
<soap:Header>
<wsse:Security>
<ds:DigestValue>
<ds:Signature>
<ds:SignedInfo>
   <ds:Reference>
     <ds:DigestValue>...</ds:DigestValue>
   </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
 <ds:KeyInfo>
   <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      <wsse:KeyIdentifier>...</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
   </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
 </ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>...</ds:SignatureValue>
</ds:Signature>
</wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
```

How can I learn what each label means or how can I generate the respective content for those labels in NodeJS?

I tried this

For `DigestValue`:

```
function calculateDigest(xmlContent) {
    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    hash.update(xmlContent);
    return hash.digest('base64');
}
```

For `SignatureValue`:

```
function signDigest(digest, privateKey) {
  const signer = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
  signer.update(digest);
  return signer.sign(privateKey, 'base64');
}
```

For `KeyIdentifier`:

```
function generateKeyIdentifier(certPem) {
  const certDer = Buffer.from(certPem.replace(/(-----(BEGIN|END) CERTIFICATE-----|\n)/g, ''), 'base64');
  return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(certDer).digest('base64');
}
```

It works but I'm not sure since the external server gives me a 500 error

Comment: Could you recommend a doc where I can learn in more detail about SOAP and XML signatures and encryption?